# How to filter searches by organization or board on Trello

Tags: trello

Any idea how this works, or if this works?  When I type in a search term, I really don't want to see every result from every public board, user, and organization on Trello.

Comment: Based on my limited testing, it seems to sort results from boards where you are a member above any other result. Knowing that might help mitigate this issue's impact.

Answer (score 1):

We're still working on our search capabilities.

As JGB146 observed, we are prioritizing cards that you're "involved" with above other search results.

Additionally, if you have a board open, and you initiate the search from there, then results from the board that you're looking at will have the highest relevance (and archived cards will be included in the search results)